# strsep() with char pointer gives segmentation fault in c

Tags: c, string

```c
int main() {
  char* instruction = "x10,   14(x2)";
  char* rd = strsep(&instruction, ",");
  printf("%c", *rd);
    
  return(0);
}
```

I was trying to run this few lines, and i was expecting it to print "x", but it gives segmentation fault. What did i do wrong?

Comment: Where were you expecting that "x" to be stored exactly?

Comment: Of course it does, `strsep` MODIFIES the string it operates on. You cannot modify a *String Literal* (except on one non-conforming compiler that will go unnamed)

Comment: I want to know, who is this compiler!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [strsep man](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html)

> ```
>  char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);
>
>  If *stringp is NULL, the strsep() function returns NULL and does
>    nothing else.  Otherwise, this function finds the first token in the
>    string *stringp, that is delimited by one of the bytes in the string
>    delim.  This token is terminated by overwriting the delimiter with a
>    null byte ('\0'), and *stringp is updated to point past the token.
>    In case no delimiter was found, the token is taken to be the entire
>    string *stringp, and *stringp is made NULL.
> ```

You are trying to modify the ready only string by passing it to `strsep`.

```
  char* instruction = "x10,   14(x2)";
  char* rd = strsep(&instruction, ",");
```

try

```
  char* instruction = "x10,   14(x2)";
  char *temp = strdup(instruction);
  char *save = temp;
  char* rd = strsep(&temp, ",");
  free(save);
```

You need to preserve a copy of the pointer to `temp` so it can be freed later.

**Example**: From the description "*stringp is updated to point past the token."*,  if you use `free(temp)` you will pass an invalid address to `free()` because `temp` no longer points to the beginning of the allocated block it points somewhere in the interior of it.